# The meaning of "Booking off/on duty"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

I am doing a translation from English to Indonesian and there is a phrase that confuses me. What does "book off/on duty" mean. For example, "I will be booking off duty shortly". I checked in a dictionary but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Booking on (or off) duty' is a very common term for starting or finishing a period of attendance at work in UK usage. I have also found examples in Canadian sources. It is often used with 'organised' occupations like firefighter, NHS paramedic, police officer, railway staff, etc or where rotas are used.

"In both cases the drivers had booked on duty around midnight, worked a train from Westbury to Acton" (UK rail accident report)

"Booked on duty at 17:00, and by 17:30 had tracked and located a male who'd decamped from a vehicle. He was found hiding deep in a hedge" (Cheshire Police officer)

I expect  that among others, prison, customs, immigration, etc, officers or security guards would use the expression too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a phrase familiar to me (and I can't find any instances in this sense in the GloWbE corpus even in Indonesian English) , but it obviously means something like *signing in at (/out from) work*. Another phrase in British English is *clocking on/off*, but I think that's dated.

Comment: In the US, *to clock **in/out*** is common.

Comment: _Clocking on/off_, of course, meant using a mechanical device attached to a clock to mark your card with the exact time you arrived/left - no doubt replaced by electronic devices nowadays.